# How to disable "command + / " in YouTube as a shortcut in macOS?

Tags: macos, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, youtube

I'm using a Mac. Regardless of the browser I use, when I am in YouTube and press command + / then the website will pop a helper modal.

In my system I have set command + / as a shortcut for other stuff. I don't want to show this helper modal in YouTube.

How do I remove this shortcut in that website?

Comment: It might be worth adding a screenshot of the dialog box that you're encountering. At least in past versions of Safari, `Command + /` was apparently used to hide or show the Status Bar.

Answer (score 0):

The modal is a "help modal" as shown below.

[image]

Can you change the shortcut?  In short, no.

Applications take precedence when it comes to defining shortcuts so, you may want to remap the <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>/</kbd> to something else.